# PS CS6: 'Rasterize image' fills selection with color

Tags: cs6, pen-tool, rasterization

I am using a pen tool to select an area in the image, which creates a new layer:
[image: Selected Shape]

After shape selection with a pen tool, make selection (pen tool -> right click -> make selection) is used (feather 0 px, anti-aliased un-ticked). Bucket tool is then used on the selected area where I receive a question if I would like to rasterize the image:
[image: Rasterize]

After pressing 'okay', image becomes rasterized (I assume), but my selected area is filled with a color (I get different colors, still haven't figured out how does PS link this color):
[image: Fill]

The problem with this fill is that its color bleeds to other pixels:
[image: Bleeding]

Finally, I still try and add the desired color (anti-alias un-ticked, contiguous ticked). The color is applied, but I am still left with the bleeding problems from the previous color (black in this case):
[image: BleedingColor]

Here is another example after 'ok' was pressed to the image rasterization:
[image: Example2]

I would like to color just the selection and using just the color I choose. This sequence was working some time before, but I cannot do this anymore. I would be grateful if someone could point me to the right direction.

EDIT AND SOLUTION:
Everything works if the pen tool is chosen for 'path', rather than 'shape':
[image: Path]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are even rasterizing it. You have an already made shape.

All you need to do is change the fill color found here:

[image]

Comment: PS blends pixel colors to the neighboring pixels and I can't seem to find a way to avoid this. I achieved this by using 'rasterize' some time before, but it does not work anymore.

Comment: @GytisBernotas, when you make a shape layer you can change its color in the toolbar from the Fill menu shown in Ovaryraptor's screenshot... or by double clicking the layer thumbnail. Your "pixel bleeding" happened because you rasterized the shape layer that had a black color fill and then you bucket filled another color on top of the black color on the same layer. If you had done the bucket fill on an empty layer, it would've worked, but you would've made the original shape layer for nothing. You could've just changed the shape layer fill to a different color and achieved the same thing.